# Slow label and picturebox event firing which are child of Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, custom-controls

i have developed custom control which inherits Button control, actually i`m creating button with one picturebox and label on Button(picturebox and label are child controls). I created same method and wired child controls to behave as clicking on parent(Button), it works but its slow no mather what i do(tried with InvokeOnClick, me.performclick, Me.OnClick(New EventArgs()), tried with same method for all events), but clicking on label or picture box is slow, i need it to be fast as clicking directly on button cause in my application is very important to be able to click on button twice in second for example, if you click on label or picturebox twice at second it will fire just one time not 2.
What i have been thinking of is to make label and picturebox invisible for event is it possible or anyother idea ?

Thanks in forward

Comment: **very** hard to tell without seeing a single byte of code, but are the picture sources really large?  if you have a lot going on in the click events (rendering a large image for instance) it is going to take some time.

Comment: My reputation is 8, cant post image to describe, no there is no thing about big pictures or anything else its just event click, i would like to be able directly click on button. I`m using same method for 3 events, label.click, picturebox.click, and button.click, button click works perfect but label and picbox event are slow on second click, does not react fast.

Comment: cant tell you anything without seeing the event **code** (not pictures) - it is the code after all that is causing the problem.  Edit your Post to show some code if you want help - DONT post in comments - they don't format code

Comment: There is no need for code in this case dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing battle with ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick.  Which is turned *on* for the PictureBox and Label controls but turned *off* for Button.

So when you are clicking rapidly on either the picturebox or the label then they'll generate the DoubleClick event instead of the Click event.  You'll interpret that as "slow" since you probably didn't write a handler for that event.  Subscribing the event and calling Me.OnClick is a workaround.

Just don't do this.  PictureBox and Label are point-and-click convenience controls but they are extraordinarily wasteful.  It takes just two lines of code in the button's OnPaint() method override to get the exact same outcome, minus the overhead and the event problems.  Use e.Graphics.DrawImage() to draw the pb's image and TextRenderer.DrawText() to draw the label's text.

Comment: Thanks a million, cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Using MouseDown event ensures the event is triggered once per click, regardless of click/doubleclick.